# /etc/hosts doesn't affect PHP

Tags: php, linux, hosts

I'm having problems with the hosts file and PHP. When running the PHP code as `root`, the entries from /etc/hosts are read. But not when running the code as my user, or from apache.

```
root@server:/# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       mydomain.com

root@server:/# php -r "echo gethostbyname('mydomain.com');"
127.0.0.1

markus@server:/$ php -r "echo gethostbyname('mydomain.com');"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Any idea why this is?

Comment: I don't think this belongs to serverfault, as PHP is involved :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you make sure your `/etc/hosts` file is world readable?

`chmod a+r /etc/hosts`

Comment: Edited `a+w` in the answer to avoid confusing others if Michael doesn't.